# Detecting AC pump motor running (from the outside)

Tags: sensor, motor, ac

My heating system at home uses a couple of [Grundfos pumps](https://product-selection.grundfos.com/product-detail.product-detail.html?productnumber=59546800&qcid=228551666) to circulate warm water. They are controlled by my heating system and as far as I can tell, running on 220V AC.

I would like to track when these pumps are running. Is there a sensor that could detect this? I don't want to connect something to my heating system, so the sensor should detect the running pump "externally".

Comment: This will produce an AC signal! I use much the same idea to control an extractor fan for an electric shower, but I use a comparator (LM311) to detect the AC and use the pulses to drive the fan control.

Answer (score 1):

A Hall effect sensor should be able to pick up the varying magnetic field when mounted near the motor. This provides a low-voltage, isolated sensor. Amplify, rectify and threshold the output to provide the digital signal.

Answer (score 0):

There are non-invasive current sensors or split-core current transformers that can be clomped around a single wire to detect current. You will need sufficient access to the wiring to place the sensor around a single wire. Tt can not detect current in a 2-wire cable.

There are also non-contact voltage sensors. One of those might work if the only wiring accessible is a cable. Those may only be available as hand-held indicators. You will need to search to see if something is available for connecting to a monitoring circuit. It might be possible to modify a hand-held device.